# Java client is not able to connect to the server which has a openSSL certificate with EC cipher

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, openssl

I have a openssl self-signed certificate with EC prime256v1 configured with tomcat 8.5.63 and using java 1.8.275. I am trying to connect a java client to the server. I have already downloaded the server certificate in the client truststore but it is giving a handshake_failure. Below are the details of the things i have done to configure the SSL server and client.

I have created a openssl server certificate using the following commands.

1. openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out tomcatkey.pem
2. openssl req -new -x509 -key tomcatkey.pem -out tomcatcert.pem -days 360
3. openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -nocrypt -in tomcatkey.pem -inform PEM -out tomcatkey.key.der -outform DER
4. openssl x509 -in tomcatcert.pem -inform PEM -out tomcatcert.crt.der -outform DER

After that I am using the ImportKey.java from AgentBob (http://www.agentbob.info/agentbob/80/version/default/part/AttachmentData/data/ImportKey.java) to create the java keystore.

This is the tomcat connector I used in server.xml

Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol" sslImplementationName="org.apache.tomcat.util.net.openssl.OpenSSLImplementation" SSLEnabled="true" enableLookups="false" acceptCount="1000" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS1.2" URIEncoding="UTF-8" keystorePass="changeit" keystoreFile="conf/keystore" keyAlias="importkey"

After that for the java client configuration I have already properly downloaded the certificate to the client truststore and also verified the same using the keytool -list command. The certificate signature algorithm is "signature algorithm": "SHA256withECDSA".

Now when I enabled the SSL debug logs below is the log that i obtained from the client.

```
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1.2",
  "random"              : "0C 55 D2 07 C4 58 74 F9 B6 98 C8 41 06 36 87 C1 E8 2F 3E 5E B7 BA AC E5 A5 C9 89 37 FE 48 33 29",
  "session id"          : "",
  "cipher suites"       : "[TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009D), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x009F), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384(0x00A3), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009C), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x009E), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256(0x00A2), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x003D), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006B), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256(0x006A), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0035), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0039), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA(0x0038), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x003C), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0067), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256(0x0040), TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x002F), TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0033), TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA(0x0032), TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV(0x00FF)]",
  "compression methods" : "00",
  "extensions"          : [
    "server_name (0)": {
      type=host_name (0), value=xpvm-135.ros.net
    },
    "supported_groups (10)": {
      "versions": [ffdhe2048, ffdhe3072, ffdhe4096, ffdhe6144, ffdhe8192]
    },
    "signature_algorithms (13)": {
      "signature schemes": [rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "signature_algorithms_cert (50)": {
      "signature schemes": [rsa_pss_rsae_sha256, rsa_pss_rsae_sha384, rsa_pss_rsae_sha512, rsa_pss_pss_sha256, rsa_pss_pss_sha384, rsa_pss_pss_sha512, rsa_pkcs1_sha256, rsa_pkcs1_sha384, rsa_pkcs1_sha512, dsa_sha256, rsa_sha224, dsa_sha224, rsa_pkcs1_sha1, dsa_sha1]
    },
    "extended_master_secret (23)": {
      <empty>
    },
    "supported_versions (43)": {
      "versions": [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    }
  ]
}
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|0E|HostAgentThread|2021-06-22 11:09:54.162 IST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:241|WRITE: TLS12 handshake, length = 223
javax.net.ssl|FINE|0E|HostAgentThread|2021-06-22 11:09:54.162 IST|SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:255|Raw write (
  0000: 16 03 03 00 DF 01 00 00   DB 03 03 0C 55 D2 07 C4  ............U...
  0010: 58 74 F9 B6 98 C8 41 06   36 87 C1 E8 2F 3E 5E B7  Xt....A.6.../>^.
  0020: BA AC E5 A5 C9 89 37 FE   48 33 29 00 00 26 00 9D  ......7.H3)..&..
  0030: 00 9F 00 A3 00 9C 00 9E   00 A2 00 3D 00 6B 00 6A  ...........=.k.j
  0040: 00 35 00 39 00 38 00 3C   00 67 00 40 00 2F 00 33  .5.9.8.<.g.@./.3
  0050: 00 32 00 FF 01 00 00 8C   00 00 00 25 00 23 00 00  .2.........%.#..
  0060: 20 78 70 76 6D 2D 31 33   35 2E 72 6F 73 2E 73 74   xpvm-135.ros.ne
  0070: 6F 72 61 67 65 2E 68 70   65 63 6F 72 70 2E 6E 65  t...............
  0080: 74 00 0A 00 0C 00 0A 01   00 01 01 01 02 01 03 01  ................
  0090: 04 00 0D 00 1E 00 1C 08   04 08 05 08 06 08 09 08  ................
  00A0: 0A 08 0B 04 01 05 01 06   01 04 02 03 01 03 02 02  ................
  00B0: 01 02 02 00 32 00 1E 00   1C 08 04 08 05 08 06 08  ....2...........
  00C0: 09 08 0A 08 0B 04 01 05   01 06 01 04 02 03 01 03  ................
  00D0: 02 02 01 02 02 00 17 00   00 00 2B 00 07 06 03 03  ..........+.....
  00E0: 03 02 03 01                                        ....
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|0E|HostAgentThread|2021-06-22 11:09:54.162 IST|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:486|Raw read (
  0000: 15 03 03 00 02                                     .....
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|0E|HostAgentThread|2021-06-22 11:09:54.162 IST|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:214|READ: TLSv1.2 alert, length = 2
javax.net.ssl|FINE|0E|HostAgentThread|2021-06-22 11:09:54.162 IST|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:486|Raw read (
  0000: 02 28                                              .(
)
javax.net.ssl|FINE|0E|HostAgentThread|2021-06-22 11:09:54.162 IST|SSLSocketInputRecord.java:247|READ: TLSv1.2 alert, length = 2
javax.net.ssl|FINE|0E|HostAgentThread|2021-06-22 11:09:54.162 IST|Alert.java:238|Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "handshake_failure"
}
```

So here I have seen that the server cipher ECDSA is not on the list of the supported ciphers of the client in ClientHello message. Is that the reason why the client handshake is failing. If that is the reason then is there some way how I can add the cipher to the client supported list or any workaround to make the handshake successful. I am already using JCE Unlimited Jurisdiction policy for the client and the server both.

Comment: Please add some details on the Java client (how do you configure it). The client sends only cipher suites, which require an RSA or DSA key, hence the handshake failure.

Comment: (1) plus the client does not allow EC in groups-formerly-curves, or sigalgs _or_ sigalgscert -- and it sends sigalgscert without offering TLS1.3 which doesn't make sense. (2) 'unlimited policy' has been unnecessary and obsolete since 8u161/2 3 years ago, as clearly stated on the Oracle website, and even before that it had no effect on EC or any asymmetric algorithm ever. (3) why bother converting to keystore when 8.5 up, especially with OpenSSLImplementation, can use the PEM files?

Comment: @piotr-p-karwasz For configuring the java client I just downloaded the server certificate to the client truststore like i mentioned earlier

Comment: @dave-thompson-085 can you please explain you first point clearly.

Comment: @Dev, what I meant is: what HTTP client are you using (there is a bunch of them) and how do you use it (please add the code to your question)? Every client has a way to configure the security parameters of the connection.

Comment: @piotr-p-karwasz I am using org.apache.xmlrpc.client.XmlRpcClient